# Example for direct sum...

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't find space $V$ with sub-spaces $W_1,W_2,W_3$ such that $V=W_1+W_2+W_3$ with  $W_i\cap W_j=\{0\}$ for $i\neq j$, but $V\neq W_1 \bigoplus W_2 \bigoplus W_3$.

Help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1** You want $W_3 \cap (W_1 + W_2) \ne \{ 0 \}$.

**Hint 2** Try to take all $W_i$ one-dimensional, then $W_3 \cap (W_1 + W_2) \ne \{ 0 \}$ means that $W_3 \subseteq \dots$

**Hint 3/Spoiler**

> Take $V = \mathbf{R}^{2}$, $W_1 = \langle (1, 0) \rangle$, $W_2 = \langle (0, 1) \rangle$, $W_3 = \langle (1, 1) \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $V=\left<e_1,e_2\right>$ (so $\dim V=2$), $W_1=\left<e_1\right>$, $W_2=\left<e_2\right>$, $W_3=\left<e_1+e_2\right>$ (one-dimensional subspaces).

Comment: @Andreas Caranti: Thank you, Andreas.

Comment: You're welcome, Boris!